# Summernote - Text displayed as raw HTML on validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-2

I am using Codeiginter with Summernote on front end - Now In a form, when some fields are empty, the same page loads with validation checking. I am  using the following JS and CI code:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
        <?php if(isset($article['text']))
         {
         ?>
        $('#summernote').code('<?php echo $article['text'];  ?>');
        <?php } else { ?>

        $('#summernote').code('<?php echo $_POST['contents'];  ?>').text();

        <?php } ?>
    });
```

Now the issue is when say, validation fails, the above code populates the Summernote editor with RAW HTML instead of formatted HTML as it should

> This is an example of my first post Pellentesque libero tortor,
>   tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo eros a enim.
>   Aenean imperdiet. Cras sagittis.
> Nam at
>   tortor in tellus interdum sagittis. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit
>   amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Etiam ut purus mattis
>   mauris sodales aliquam. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Phasellus
>   tempus.

Any ideas why is this so? I have tried .val and .html  - but they don't work. Kindly help.

Comment: If html() doesn't work we need the output of <?php echo $article['text'];  ?> probably you have something weird there

Comment: remove `.text()` from your else block and try again to see if it works.

Comment: I tried to remove .text() hasn't worked. 
@Michelem: $_POST['contents'] is applied when validation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. After two days of intense efforts - I found out the reason - it's stupid. Codeigniter form-validation encodes all formatted data with escape characters and converts them into raw HTML. To solve this problem, remove the validation for contents in your form_validation.php or your form validation rules. Then you can output using

```
 $('#summernote').code(<?php echo $this->input->post('contents');?>);
```

Thanks everybody for help, though.

Answer (score 2):

With all respect to your own answer I have a few more things to say too since this is a generic problem. Frankly it is not so stupid, modern frameworks does this, they escape the html chars if you don't tell to do otherwise.

In your case(**Codeigniter**) telling not to escape is in validation part.

In my case(**.net mvc razor views**) you can do:

```
$('#summernote').code("@Html.Raw("<div>your html string</div>")");
```

Comment: Where to add that code? My code is: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#summernote').summernote({
  height: "500px"
 });     
});
var postForm = function() {
 var content = $('textarea[name="content"]').html($('#summernote').code());
}

</script>

Comment: First initialize: `$('#summernote').summernote({ height: "500px" });` and then set the content: `$('#summernote').code($('textarea[name="content"]').html())`. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Where you add the content there? For example <storng>content here...</strong>

Comment: Wooh, solved the issue differently. Just put my HTML in DIV and then created hidden textarea and fired the DIV content with JS to the hidden textarea on form submit.

Comment: Yeah, glad you've found a way out. It just requires to play a little bit with it till you find a solution - it is a good tool.

Answer (score 0):

Change code with html:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    <?php if(isset($article['text']))
     {
     ?>
    $('#summernote').html('<?php echo $article['text'];  ?>');
    <?php } else { ?>

    $('#summernote').html('<?php echo $_POST['contents'];  ?>');

    <?php } ?>
});
```

Comment: Can you try something like this:  $('#summernote').html('<strong>HELLO WORLD</strong>'); if this works, so it's the PHP echoing non-html string

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
$(window).load(function(){

    // set content 
    <?php if(isset($article['text'])) { ?>
    $('#summernote').html('<?php echo $article['text'];  ?>');
    <?php } else { ?>
    $('#summernote').html('<?php echo $_POST['contents'];  ?>');
    <?php } ?>

    // create editor 
    $("#summernote").summernote();
});
```

or

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    // create editor 
    $('#summernote').summernote();

    // set content 
    <?php if(isset($article['text'])) { ?>
    $('#summernote').code('<?php echo $article['text'];  ?>');
    <?php } else { ?>
    $('#summernote').code('<?php echo $_POST['contents'];  ?>');
    <?php } ?>
});
```

Comment: Both versions will have the HTML code in summernote. How to have the formatter text in summernote. For example I want to have in summernote <strong>text</strong> but that what I see there. Would like to see there just "text" but in bold. On code view I see: &lt;strong&gt;text&lt;/strong&gt;